# Create a nested tree from list

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

From a list of lists, I would like to create a nested dictionary of which the keys would point to the next value in the sublist. In addition, I would like to count the number of times a sequence of sublist values occurred.

Example:

From a list of lists as such:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'],
['a', 'c'],
['b']]
```

I would like to create a nested dictionary as such:

```
{
  'a': {
          {'b': 
                {
                'c':{}
                'count_a_b_c': 1
                }
            'count_a_b*': 1
          }, 
          {'c': {},
           'count_a_c': 1
          }
          'count_a*': 2
        },
  {
  'b':{},
  'count_b':1
  }
}
```

Please note that the names of the keys for counts do **not** matter, they were named as such for illustration.

Comment: Have you made any attempts to accomplish this that you are able to share?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of my attempts were fruitful. I did spend several hours on the problem. The main problem is how to automate the nested structure with a for loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was curious how i would do this and came up with this:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
['a', 'c'],
['b']]

tree = {}
for branch in lst:
    count_str = 'count_*'
    last_node = branch[-1]
    cur_tree = tree
    for node in branch:
        if node == last_node:
            count_str = count_str[:-2] + f'_{node}'
        else:
            count_str = count_str[:-2] + f'_{node}_*'
        cur_tree[count_str] = cur_tree.get(count_str, 0) + 1
        cur_tree = cur_tree.setdefault(node, {})
```

nothing special happening here...

for your example:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(tree, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

produces:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {},
            "count_a_b_c": 1
        },
        "c": {},
        "count_a_b_*": 1,
        "count_a_c": 1
    },
    "b": {},
    "count_a_*": 2,
    "count_b": 1
}
```

it does not exactly reproduce what you imagine - but that is in part due to the fact that your desired result is not a valid python dictionary...

but it may be a starting point for you to solve your problem.

Comment: could you pls take a look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636774/constructing-a-tree-view-from-a-nested-list-using-anytree-treelib)