# constructing a tree view from a nested list with duplicate subtrees (using anytree/treelib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, treeview, anytree

I have a nested list like the following:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'e'],      # this e is the branch of b
       ['a', 'f', 'e'],      # this e is the branch of f,
       ['a', 'h', 'i i i']]  # string with spaces
```

and I wanna to construct a tree like:

```
a
├── b
│   └── e
├── f
|   └── e
└── h
    └── i i i
```

I want to use either of the two packages: [treelib](https://treelib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/treelib.html#treelib.tree.Tree.paths_to_leaves) and [anytree](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I've read many posts and tried many different methods and didn't make it work.

**Update:**

I came up with the following method, but the problems I have now are

1. the vertical order of the branches (e.g., "b", "f", "h") is not guaranteed (when I have many lists in a list ).
2. "e" as a branch of "f" won't show up

```
from treelib import Node, Tree

# make list flat
lst = sum([i for i in lst], [])

tree = Tree()
tree_dict = {}

# create root node
tree_dict[lst[0]] = tree.create_node(lst[0])

for index, item in enumerate(lst[1:], start=1):
    if item not in tree_dict.keys():
        partent_node = tree_dict[lst[index-1]]
        tree_dict[item] = tree.create_node(item, parent=partent_node)

tree.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i looked into [`anytree`](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and came up with this:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

lst = [["a", "b", "c", "e"], ["a", "b", "f"], ["a", "b", "c", "g", "h"], ["a", "i"]]


def list_to_anytree(lst):
    root_name = lst[0][0]
    root_node = Node(root_name)
    nodes = {root_name: root_node}  # keeping a dict of the nodes
    for branch in lst:
        assert branch[0] == root_name
        for parent_name, node_name in zip(branch, branch[1:]):
            node = nodes.setdefault(node_name, Node(node_name))
            parent_node = nodes[parent_name]
            if node.parent is not None:
                assert node.parent.name == parent_name
            else:
                node.parent = parent_node
    return root_node


anytree = list_to_anytree(lst)
for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(anytree):
    print(f"{pre}{node.name}")
```

there is not much happening here. i just convert your list to anytree nodes (and `assert` the list representation is valid while doing that). and i keep a dictionary of the nodes i already have in `nodes`.

the output is indeed

```
a
├── b
│   ├── c
│   │   ├── e
│   │   └── g
│   │       └── h
│   └── f
└── i
```

---

if you have multiple nodes with the same name you can not use the `dict` above; you need to iterate from the root node over the children:

```
def list_to_anytree(lst):
    root_name = lst[0][0]
    root_node = Node(root_name)
    for branch in lst:
        parent_node = root_node
        assert branch[0] == parent_node.name
        for cur_node_name in branch[1:]:
            cur_node = next(
                (node for node in parent_node.children if node.name == cur_node_name),
                None,
            )
            if cur_node is None:
                cur_node = Node(cur_node_name, parent=parent_node)
            parent_node = cur_node
    return root_node
```

your example

```
lst = [
    ["a", "b", "e"],  # this e is the branch of b
    ["a", "f", "e"],  # this e is the branch of f,
    ["a", "h", "i i i"],
]

anytree = list_to_anytree(lst)
for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(anytree):
    print(f"{pre}{node.name}")
```

then gives:

```
a
├── b
│   └── e
├── f
│   └── e
└── h
    └── i i i
```

Comment: Hi buddy. For some reasons, I keep getting an AssertError with strings having spaces. Could you please take a look at my updated questions?

Comment: hi @steven! the problem is not the node with spaces, but you have two nodes named `e` with different parents. if no need to allow for that i'd need to change the logic a bit (my `nodes` dictionary will not work...).

Comment: Hi, buddy. Is there an alternative of using next() to make the code a little bit shorter?

Comment: not that i know of... see e.g. this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361426/get-the-first-item-from-an-iterable-that-matches-a-condition . you could pack that into a function (factor it out): `def next_child(cur_node_name, parent_node): return next(...)`